# 0Auth 2.0 Getting JWT with Keys using postman

Tags: jwk

I am trying to get authorization from a FHIR server using JSON Web Key using POSTMAN. This is very new to me and I am trying to understand how this works.

I have a public and private key already generated. I gave the key to the authorization server. I am using [this](http://hl7.org/fhir/uv/bulkdata/STU1.0.1/authorization/index.html) as a guide, but still not sure what to do next.

What I am looking for is, an explanation of how the JWK works with getting the authorization token and/or something that kinda show me how it works in POSTMAN.